# On Integrating the joint probability density function of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that the joint probability density function of two random variables $x$ and $y$ is given as $p(x,y)$. We know that the probability density function of $x$ can be found by integrating out $y$ i.e.

\begin{equation}
p(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x,y)dy
\end{equation}

While doing some calculation, I performed the following calculation by mistake.

\begin{equation}
Z = \int_{-\infty}^{y^*} p(x,y)dy
\end{equation}

and I don't know what should I call $Z$. Is it the probability distribution function of $y$? If not, what is it that I calculated by mistake? My actual intention was to perform the integration on the entire real line.

Comment: what is y* the limit of integration?

Comment: $y^*$ is a deterministic variable and may also be treated as one of the realizations of $y$.

Answer (score 1):

If the integral converges, then the result is a product of the probability density function for $X$ at $x$, and the conditional cumulative distribution function for $Y$ at $y^\star$ given $X=x$.  This mixture will be a bivariate function so...

$\qquad\begin{align}Z(x,y^\star) &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{y^\star} p(x, \mathscr y)\,\mathrm d\mathscr y \\ &= p(x)\,\mathsf P(Y\leqslant y^\star\mid X=x)\end{align}$

Answer (score -1):

The expression $w:= p(x) Z$ is a real number, not a random variable. This value $w$ is known as the *conditional probability that $Y \leq y^*$ given that $X=x$*.

A reference is equation (8.16) in Klenke, Probability theory, e.g. [in google books](https://books.google.de/books?id=xDy3BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA169&ots=u6TenudpnG&dq=klenke%20conditional%20probability&hl=de&pg=PA183#v=onepage&q=klenke%20conditional%20probability&f=false). If an example is preferred, then [Conditional probabilities from a joint density function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339643/conditional-probabilities-from-a-joint-density-function) is a good one.